# Rails 5 link_to unscoped path in scoped controller view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-routing

I got a strange issue

this is my routes.rb

```
get '/fin', to: 'pages#fin'
mount S::Engine => '/pod'
S::Engine.routes.draw do
  resources :articles, only: [:show, :index], path: 'posts'    
root 'articles#index'
```

not let say I go to my root path of the S engine. inside the view I'm trying to put a link to '/fin' so I write

```
<%= link_to "Fin", fin_path %>
```

But I get an unknown route error.

I also tried to use the controller:'/pages' to solve the controller resolving, but it didn't help

> like this: url_for controller:'/pages',action:"fin"

The route exists, and the problem is related somehow to the scoping.

thanks,

Comment: does your `rake routes` include `fin_path` ?

Comment: My rake routes relevant line is  fin GET  /fin(.:format)                    pages#fin

the issue is within the scoping

Answer (score 0):

Try: get 'fin', to: 'pages#fin' and then try to run rake routes in your terminal to see if fin_path is there. Also what do you have in your fin method in your pages controller?

Comment: Got nothing, but it's important to understand that fin_path works in for example PagesController layout